# Passing a local javascript variable to global on a Phaser game using a button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, phaser-framework

On a simple Phaser game I'm developing, I need a "submit score" button that passes a local javascript score variable to global so I can pass it to its PHP page and, finally, put inside a MySQL table. The problem is that I couldn't find a way to do it properly.

This is the button creation (located on the loading state):

```
this.add.button(50, 200, 'grass:1x1', score(PlayState.coinPickupCount), this);
```

This is the function 'score' that the button calls (outside the states):

```
function score(points) {

var gscore = points;

return points;

}
```

This is where coinPickupCount is located:

```
PlayState.init = function (data) {
this.keys = this.game.input.keyboard.addKeys({
    left: Phaser.KeyCode.LEFT,
    right: Phaser.KeyCode.RIGHT,
    up: Phaser.KeyCode.UP
});

this.coinPickupCount = 0; //the game score
this.hasKey = false;
this.level = (data.level || 0) % LEVEL_COUNT;
};
```

coinPickupCount already increases by 1 everytime a coin is picked up, and it is the variable I want to be passed to global everytime I press the "submit score" button.

Almost all of my code was downloaded from that link:

https://mozdevs.github.io/html5-games-workshop/platformer/js/main.js

Thank you for taking your time! I accept any other way to get that variable to the PHP page that the game appears and I'm forced to use MySQL because it's a school project.

Comment: You can use a [ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) request.

Comment: Ok, i'm going to read that and try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the database without page refreshing you must use an ajax request.

Add ajax request to your score function :

```
function score( points ) {

  var gscore = points;

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     // If you want do something after update complate
    }
  };

  xhttp.open( "POST", "updateScore.php", true );
  xhttp.send( "points=" + points);

  return points;
}
```

And you need to create the updateScore.php file,
It needs to be something like this:

```
<?php
    if( isset( $_POST['points'] ) ){
        $points = $_POST['points'];

        // Do here SQL query or whatever you want
    }
?>
```

I hope I was helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare the variable 'coinPickUpCount' at the top of the program. In Phaser there is an already present function create() which is called by Phaser at the very start. Initialize 'coinPickupCount' there.

```
var coinPickupCount;
function create(){
 coinPickupCount = 0;
}
```

In the function 'score', increment and saved it in the database.

Comment: The problem is that almost everything on my code is from that workshop: https://mozdevs.github.io/html5-games-workshop/en/guides/platformer/start-here/ (the full code can be downloaded at the last step) and its code looks different from what I normally see on Phaser games. It works but feels confusing.

Comment: The link to most of my code is now at the question.

Comment: @Kylbert Let me understand exactly what you are trying to do.
Only when you press the variable button coinPickupCount will increase by 1?

If so, you can do within the score function, just like this:
`PlayState.coinPickupCount++;`

Comment: It already increments coinPickupCount by 1 when I pickup a coin, but what I wanted is a "submit score" button that passes all my current collected coins to global so I can pass it to my php page and then to a MySQL database.

Comment: @Kylbert Ok, So it's what I answer you at first. Use ajax request.

I will answer you now with full code example.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to reference a variable/member in one Phaser.State from another Phaser.State.
So you have `PlayState` with a variable `coinPickupCount`, and a `LoadState` with a function `score`.
I don't understand why there is user interaction in the loading state, because usually it is just used for loading the levels/assets etc.
So to me it would be more logical to put that button in the `PlayState`.

But anyway, you can't reference the variable in the declaration because it hasn't been instantiated yet. So instead of passing it as a variable, I think you have to reference it via the `game` object, something like this:

```
LoadState.create = function () {
    this.add.button(50, 200, 'grass:1x1', score(), this);
}

score = function () {
    var sc = game.state.states['PlayState'].coinPickupCount;
    sc = sc + 1;
    return sc;
}
```